# How to implement oauth in a chrome app to access a service on an appengine app

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-chrome-app

I am working on a chrome app which is using an appengine app as a backend. Usually it is possible to use the Google OAuth or the deprecated Google ClientLogin to obtain the ACSID token. The chrome app API provides [identity](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity.html) to support oauth2 in chrome apps.

I am able to get an auth token, but am failing in converting it into a valid ACSID token. I have done successfully something similar on android. The key was that when asking for the auth token, I had to specify the specific service ("ah" for the appengine). Could anyone point me out what should be the scope and how to configure the outh2 params in the manifest file?!

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Ive done oauth from a chrome extension the raw way (without using chrome identity). Its possible, I used a special oauth library for extensions. If you do that way you can do as you did from android.

Comment: @ZigMandel You might be right regarding chrome extensions. It looks like the chrome apps apply more restrictive Content Security Policies.

Comment: Aha, I had to disable some security stuff from the manifest to allow some js things.

Comment: Yes I had to do the same on my extension. Dont remember which of these did the trick for oauth:  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"

Comment: As I said the CSP cannot be relaxed for script-src and some other items when running as a packaged chrome app.

Comment: I wonder has anyone else come across this problem?!